# Poisson statistics and exponential functions!

Tags: random-variables, exponential-function, poisson-distribution, poisson-process, poisson-geometry

Would there be any chance of having a single exponential function outputting poisson data? I mean I have a $y=\exp{\left(\frac{t}{\text{constant}}\right)}$, this is not a probability but can it be generated with trains of poisson data. I appreciate your answer, in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Are you saying you have access to Poisson random variables and want to generate Exponential random variables, or that you have access to Exponential random variables and want to generate Poisson random variables, or something else entirely?

Comment: (Now stimulate the neuron with addition of 100 of exp(-t/constant) inputs, with Poisson spike trains, each with an intensity (ﬁring rate) of 10 spikes/second. )This is all i have. I add the 100 exps but what does it mean to have it with poisson??